# How to fix "Invalid format of field 'X'"

Tags: biblatex, formatting

When I'm compiling my tex-files, I'm getting this error:

```
pdflatex> Package biblatex Warning: BibTeX reported the following issues
pdflatex> (biblatex)                with 'xyz':
pdflatex> (biblatex)                - Invalid format of field 'month'.
```

It is clear what the message want's to say to me :-) But how do I have to format the field? The same question with urldate... is there a website where I can look for formatting guidelines?

The bibtex-entry which causes trouble is for example this one:

```
@article{Foster02what,
    Author = {Ian Foster},
    Date-Added = {2011-03-31 11:56:42 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2011-05-23 21:42:29 +0200},
    Journal = {GRIDtoday},
    Month = {jun},
    Title = {{What is the Grid? A Three Point Checklist}},
    Url = {http://www-fp.mcs.anl.gov/\~{}foster/Articles/WhatIsTheGrid.pdf},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = 2002,
    Bdsk-File-1 = {YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUIJid...AAAAAAAAAAAMR},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www-fp.mcs.anl.gov/%5C~%7B%7Dfoster/Articles/WhatIsTheGrid.pdf}}
```

EDIT: ok I found the mistake: the month field must have the format month=6. I have to tell BibDesk to write it that way without {} around it :-)

Comment: No, the month just needs to be numeric. `month={6}` is a completely valid format for the field.

Comment: I'm getting the error with Month={6}, with Month=6 not :-/ That's the reason for my other question with bibdesk...

Comment: Then make a MWE with two sample bib entries that shows exactly the error you are getting and add it to that question.

Comment: I think this is the answer you were looking for:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28240/160474

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the `biblatex` documentation:

> 2.3.8 Date Specifications
>
> The date fields date, origdate, eventdate, and
>   urldate require a date specification
>   in yyyy-mm-dd format. Date ranges are
>   given as yyyy-mm-dd/yyyy-mm-dd.
>   Partial dates are valid provided that
>   date components are omitted at the end
>   only. You may specify an open ended
>   date range by giving the range
>   separator and omitting the end date
>   (e. g., yyyy/). See table 2 for some
>   examples of valid date specifications
>   and the formatted date autmatically
>   generated by biblatex. The formatted
>   date is language specific and will be
>   adapted automatically. If there is no
>   date field in an entry, biblatex will
>   also consider the fields year and
>   month for backwards compatibility with
>   traditional BibTeX. Style author
>   should note that date fields like date
>   or origdate are only available in the
>   bib file. All dates are parsed and
>   dissected into their components as the
>   bib file is processed. The date
>   components are made available to
>   styles by way of the special fields
>   discussed in § 4.2.4.3. See this
>   section and table 7 on page 126 for
>   further information.

Comment: I accepted your answer because of your hint to the right place in the documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`biber`](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) backend for `biblatex` like so

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

also lets you use the three-letter abbreviations in your `bib` file.

If you are on Ubuntu > 12.10 you can install `biber` by clicking the button below
[image]
<sub>(source: [hostmar.co](https://hostmar.co/software-banner))</sub>

Comment: Actually I'm using biber as backend, and it still gives the same error, like "legacy month field 'Feb' in entry 'entry' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly."

Comment: month is now a legacy field, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386058/16419 for the proper way to do this