# Correct format of month field with bibtex

Tags: bibtex

Multiple sources, [btxFAQ](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxFAQ.pdf), [Latex Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201529831) and btxdoc.pdf , state that usage of three letter month macro is recommended format to input months. E.g. `month = nov,` is recommended.

Other sources like Wikibook uses plain string `month = "November",` and Tame the BeaST mentions all three: abbreviated macros, strings and integers: `month = 11,` or `month = 11,`.

Why should I use something else then three letter macros? Is there any sane use cases for integers or strings? As far as I understand using anything else than macros will cause problems with non-english languages, so why those sources are advocating format which will cause problems later. Are they giving bad advice for newcomers?

Note: I had to break links because link limit.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be best if you describe your situation with some code (MWE).

Comment: With biblatex you should use integers (and at best the date field and not month). (You are saying biblatex in the title of your question!).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fixed title

Comment: You ask, "Why should I use something else then three letter macros?" Maybe because a person might obtain a lot of bib entries from Zotero, ScienceDirect, and other online source and because the entries provided by these sites feature fields formatted as `month = "November"` instead of `month = nov`?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27898/

Answer (score 1):

BibTeX, the program, neither defines the bibliography entry types (e.g., book, article, proceedings, phdthesis, misc) nor the list of entry fields (e.g., title, author, address, year, month), nor if an entry field is required/mandatory for an entry type or optional or ignored.  And it doesn't define any macro - or abbreviation - for an entry field (like "nov" for "November").

All these things are defined by the used BibTeX style file (".bst") you are using.
It is similar to the relationship between TeX, the program, which defines only a small set of primitive commands, and the macro framework (PlainTeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt) you finally use as an author, which implements all of the complex things for you to make it easier to typeset a document.

Leslie Lamport's LaTeX book (1st edition 1986, 2nd edition 1994 - section "The Bibliography Database") and Oren Patashnik's ["BibTeXing"](https://ctan.net/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxdoc.pdf) and ["Designing BibTeX Styles"](https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxhak.pdf) documents in conjunction with the standard set of BibTeX .bst files (plain.bst, abbrv.bst, alpha.bst, unsrt.bast) has described and defined a de facto basic standard set of BibTeX entry types, entry fields, and BibTeX macros/abbreviations to be used in many .bib bibliography files.

Most of the newer .bst BibTeX style files keep these basic set of entry types, fields, macros, and add new entry types, new fields, and add new functions.

Back to the questions:

> Why should I use something else then three letter macros?

I prefer to use the three letter macros for the months to allow and simplify language specific formatting of the date, assuming that all .bst files will define them.

> Is there any sane use cases for integers or strings?

Yes, it is simpler to generate by external sources of bibliography entries to generate their internal representation.  If you see integers or strings I assume that the implementor was unsure if the month macros are safe to be used in an .bib export file.

No, I think that the use of integers as month field value is not preferred, because the .bst file has to implement a mapping from integer to month name in the entry type output function.  The same applies to fixed strings if you want to simplify the adaption for different languages.  Note: [BibLaTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) describes the field "month" as an integer which is formatted accordingly (if you are using month macros in the .bib entry, the BibLaTeX .bst file can define the macro to the needed integer.

> why those sources are advocating format which will cause problems later.

The major problem is that the macro/abbreviation is a BibTeX addon function, and there is no definitive guide defining a mandatory basic set of macros/abbreviations which can and shall be used by users and program's export function in bibliography .bib files and which shall be implemented by all .bst files.

If such a definitive guide exists, how to proceed with the huge set of existing .bst files: who decides which .bst is obsolete, who is able and willing to update .bst files still in use?  And what shall be in the BibTeX definitive guide?  ([BibLaTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) defines a huge set of things)