# Cite a website with date

Tags: biblatex, date

I'm trying to create a website bibliography, but the `urldate` is not being shown, only the year when the website was last update.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=nyt,style=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}   
\addbibresource{Literatur} 

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
{\ifentrytype{online}{\bibopenparen}{\bibopenbracket}
\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}
\usebibmacro{cite}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}
\ifentrytype{online}{\bibcloseparen}{\bibclosebracket}}

\begin{filecontents}{\Literature.bib}
@online{Wikipedia.27.02.2017,
 author = {Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia},
 year = {2017},
 title = {MALDI-TOF},
 url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MALDI-TOF},
 urldate = {02.06.2017}
}

\begin{document}

\parencite{Wikipedia.27.02.2017}

\newpage
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{Internet Sources}}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={ Internet Sources },type=online]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You must enter the date in the right format: `urldate={2017-06-02}`

Comment: Your MWE doesn't compile btw: undefined `\fancyhead`, undefined `\Literature`, missing `\end{filecontents}`… you should always *test* your MWE before posting it!

Comment: See also [biblatex error: invalid format of field 'date' - what's wrong?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229839/35864), [How to fix “Invalid format of field 'X'”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18896/35864)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the date in `biblatex`'s date fields in a certain way. From the manual:

> Date fields such as the default data model dates `date`, `origdate`,
>   `eventdate`, and `urldate` adhere to [EDTF (Extended Date/Time Format)](https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/pre-submission.html)
>   specification levels 0 and 1.

This will most times mean `yyyy-mm-dd`, so in your case:

```
urldate={2017-06-02}
```